# rotate video file in win8 metro app

Tags: c#, video, rotation, microsoft-metro

I have observe the properties by code  as below

```
VideoProperties videoProperties = await file.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
List<string> tmp = new List<string> { };
var fileProperties2 = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(tmp);
foreach (var p in fileProperties2)
{                    
    Debug.WriteLine(p);  
}
```

I  notice that the property "`System.Video.Orientation`"  is different from two video stream (When MSFT camera  ap  is recording video  in `Landscape` and `Portrait`)
My question is that is there any way to modify this property?
May I use `MF_MT_XXX` Media Type? (the detail property is as below shortcut)
( http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/apps/hh452756.aspx )
or is there other method to modify this property?
I have tried many method but failed to set this property.

Comment: I have found the answer
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/4014e292-0342-4882-b4ed-a12406df727b/#bfbebae2-dd64-47c4-a057-ad82334a8ea9

var MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION = new Guid("{C380465D-2271-428C-9B83-ECEA3B4A85C1}");
       recordProfile.Video.Properties[MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION] = (UInt32)180;